# Como aumentar o gráfico sem quebrar o layout em mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-3

Problema: Criei uma gráfico utilizando a API do google, porém tive que deixar o gráfico pequeno para quando tiver em mobile ele não quebrar. O problema é em tamanho para desktop fica inviável.

Como tem que ficar:
Gostaria que o gráfico ocupasse o tamanho de col 12 desktop e quando fosse para mobile ele respeitasse a largura do mesmo.

Código HTML:

```
 <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div id="" class="card-white">
            <div class="panel-heading">

            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="row">


                        <div class="col-xs-12" id="teste" ></div>


                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Script:

```
 function carregarGraficoTeste() {
        // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Legenda 1', 'Legenda 2', 'Legenda 3', 'Legenda 4', 'Legenda 5', 'Legenda 6', 'Legenda 7'],
            ['Inserir texto', 165, 938, 522, 998, 450, 614.6],
            ['Inserir texto', 135, 1120, 599, 1268, 288, 682],
            ['Inserir texto', 157, 1167, 587, 807, 397, 623],
            ['Inserir texto', 139, 1110, 615, 968, 215, 609.4],
            ['Inserir texto', 136, 691, 629, 1026, 366, 569.6]
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'apenas um teste',
            legend: { position: 'bottom', maxLines: 2 },
            seriesType: 'bars',
            height: 300,
            width: 400

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('teste'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo com o [gráfico responsivo](https://codepen.io/hemersonvianna/pen/mZgLBx). Ele não estipula tamanho, controla o mesmo por css, e no javascript ele reconhece quando o tamanho da tela muda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deu certo, obrigadão.